# How do I attract users back to an edited question?

Tags: discussion, bounties, duplicate-questions

I had posted a question some days back on SO, but due to lack of knowledge my description in the question wasn't very informative. So I did not get good replies which answered my question.

I did some research myself, but still haven't found answer to the question. However now I edited my question to clearly ask what I am looking for. After editing I do not see my question being viewed or any new answer posted. Is the edited question shown up in the newly asked questions list.

Should I post a new question for it. Even putting a bounty hasnt helped

What should be done in such a case?

Comment: Link to the question in questions?

Comment: @dmckee, I believe it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434076

Comment: @Yogesh: you only just edited the question 7 hours ago. And "vim" isn't the most popular tag on SO, and it's the _weekend_ most places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the community user automatically bumps questions every now and then, but I don't know the exact rules.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

- When you edited the question it was bumped back to the home page. Please please please don't duplicate the question.
- You *just* edited it and replied to some of the comments asking for clarification to ping them for new insight. Either way, its Friday (and now the weekend) - you'd be surprised how many actually have lives outside SO and will likely get to it on Monday instead of working.
- A bounty only guarantees that more people will look at it, not that you'll get more and/or better answers. I think a better rephrasing of the question (on Monday) would better help than the bounty.