# Editing a question doesn't give a response back from the community

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I recently went in and looked a the questions I have asked on SO. I did a total overhaul on all questions because I realized how confusing and misleading they were. However even after doing this I found there was no change at all (nobody went and up / down voted it). Seeing as I'm trying to get back permission to ask questions this was quite disappointing.

I found a post like this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42975/how-do-i-attract-users-back-to-an-edited-question) yet they didn't exactly give the best answer.

So my question is, how do I get community attention back on the questions I've asked in the past, that weren't very good, but then went back and edited to make them better?

Comment: So you're saying that you're question banned and you can't get out of it?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Seth I can't ask question because of the questions I've asked in the past. I later went back and fixed this questions yet I have not gotten a response back from the community on weather or not the questions are more clear and better.

Comment: @Bart How do I get community attention back on the questions I've asked in the past, that weren't very good, but then went back and edited to make them better.

Comment: @Griffin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Yet some of my questions are answered. Yet I still want they to be re-looked at because they are better now.

Comment: Well, besides editing them substantially to improve them, the only other choice is to award bounties. That said, your questions might have well gotten attention, but not attracted votes.

Comment: That's kind of my problem. I improved them as best I could but people don't look at them again so they can't up vote them.

Comment: Then all that remains for you is to positively contribute in other ways still possible to you and gain reputation. Either through answering, or by getting reputation through accepted edits.

Comment: @Bart That's what I feared. The questions I've asked on SO aren't very advanced because I'm not very advanced yet a lot of you are. That kind of puts me at a disadvantage.

Comment: Have you deleted any of your questions? Or were any of your questions deleted? If so, having them undeleted and improving those might help.

Comment: @Bart Most likely but if I deleted them it most likely was because it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest answering questions for a while. Your questions aren't that great -- not downvote material but not really upvote material either from my POV. I upvoted the decimal places one, because it came out of a misconception and the downvotes were more or less because people thought it stupid. Normally I'd suggest you edit them further, but I don't know what sort of edit will fix them :/

Comment: Same problem I'm having. I fixed them as best as possible but I don't know how to fix them more.